# BufferedImage / ImageIcon null pointer exception

Tags: java, image

Image, https://spooker.cc/spooker3.png

Code:

```
    private JLabel getSpookerImage() {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://spooker.cc/spooker3.png");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        return new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:240)
at cc.spooker.ui.tabs.MainTab.getSpookerImage(MainTab.java:63)
at cc.spooker.ui.tabs.MainTab.getDestructPanel(MainTab.java:53)
at cc.spooker.ui.tabs.MainTab.<init>(MainTab.java:35)
at cc.spooker.ui.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:35)
at cc.spooker.Server.<init>(Server.java:21)
at cc.spooker.Main.main(Main.java:8)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Perhaps because the image has a blank background? Not a clue, any help?

Comment: which line produces the `Exception` ?

Comment: He posted the stack trace.

Comment: @AlexR I know, I'm asking which is line `63`

Comment: @Shashwat Oh I see what you mean. I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

The `ImageIO.Read()` method is looking for an image reader to use for your image, and it isn't able to find one, so it's returning null. the `read()` method accepts a PNG, so my guess is that your image is not a valid PNG file. Try re-exporting it as a PNG or however you created it to ensure that it is not malformed in some way. I tested similar code with the PNG file here:

http://mrose.org/cc/png-test.png

And it works fine.